# Setting Presto with MySQL connector

Tags: mysql, presto

I have one issue with setting up presto server to connect with mysql database.

- the presto server is running with a docker container.
- mysql installed via terminal commands, confirmed mysql server running no problem.
- presto server running no issues. with correct configurations read, loading the correct connector configurations to connect to mysql

However, when running presto with cli, connecting to the running server, select the catalog, and then run SHOW SCHEMAS, it timed out.

What would be the potential issues and how to fix?
Seeking help from presto experts. Thanks!

expecting a solution of fixing the above issues, so that I could run presto query to query the mysql database

Comment: Would you mind posting your logs? I'm guessing it might be something related to the inter-container communication